# How to make a piece of code to be executed after I get my json request?

Tags: android, android-volley

```
public void doMySearch(List<String> IDs) {

    for (String Id : IDs) {


        String url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + Id + "?embed=nextepisode";

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println("ONREQUEST ");

                        try {

                            String name = response.getString("name");
                            String airdate = response.getJSONObject("_embedded").getJSONObject("nextepisode").getString("airdate");

                            HashMap<String, String> episodesToDisplay = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            episodesToDisplay.put(name, airdate);
                            listOfEpisodes.add(episodesToDisplay);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
        System.out.println("BEFORE ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE ");
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
        System.out.println("AFTER ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE ");
    }
    System.out.println("AFTER FOR LOOP ");
}
```

See my prints in the code, the output I get with 4 items in my IDs list is:

```
BEFORE ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
AFTER ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
BEFORE ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
AFTER ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
BEFORE ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
AFTER ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
BEFORE ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
AFTER ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE
AFTER FOR LOOP
ONREQUEST
ONREQUEST
ONREQUEST
ONREQUEST
```

The point is `System.out.println("AFTER FOR LOOP ");` is executed before `onRequest` and I want it to call a function in that place which would use a list populated inside `onRequest`. I thought onRequest would be executed after adding items to queue but it's not. Is there any way I can make it work in the order I expect? I cannot call funtion inside `onRequest` since I want it to use fully populated list and onRequest is called many times at once.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a callback to it.

Like this

```
public interface VolleyCallback {
    void onSuccess(String string);

    void onFailure(VolleyError error);
}
```

Then when you call your doMySearch function, you pass your callback, like this:

```
doMySearch(ids, new VolleyCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(String response) {
   Log.d("Success", response);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(VolleyError error) {                                                              
   Log.e("Error", "ops thats an error!");
  }
});
```

And finally, on your doMySearch function, where you override the onResponse and onErrorResponse listener you call your callback, like this:

```
    public void doMySearch(List<String> IDs, final VolleyCallback callback) {
    for (String Id : IDs) {

        String url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + Id + "?embed=nextepisode";

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println("ONREQUEST ");

                        callback.onSuccess("ONREQUEST");

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        callback.onFailure(error);
                    }
                });
        System.out.println("BEFORE ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE ");
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
        System.out.println("AFTER ADD TO REQUEST QUEUE ");
    }
    System.out.println("AFTER FOR LOOP ");
}
```

Comment: Read my post, there is ax example of how to call your doMySearch function, the second piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

Your code block is executed async, so you have to put your code inside the onResponse method.